# How do I put values in an external files in size order using python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to create a leader board for a quiz that I am creating. I have wrote the code to write the users name and their score in an external file, and they are currently in the order of which they were sent there, like so:

```
Ethan, 15
James, 20
Daniel, 7
```

I want to put them into size order so they look like so:

```
James, 20
Ethan, 15
Daniel, 7
```

I have spent quite while trying to figure it out but I am having a lot of trouble. I would really appreciate it if someone could help.

This is the code I am using to send the data to an external file:

```
file = open("Scores.txt","a")
file.write(supplied_Username)
file.write(",")
file.write(str(score))
file.write("\n")
file.close()
```

Comment: show us your code? what data structure are you using to store record in your code before writing it to a fie?

Comment: I edited the post and added it to the bottom. I'm new to this website, I will remember to add more detail next time, thanks.

Comment: is your `supplied_username` and score both stored as separate string? can you post further code? its better to use something like `dict` to store `username` as `key` and score as `value`

Comment: The code is for a project I am doing in school which need to have a login system involved. The supplied_Username is from when the user logs in and the score is from when the user completes the quiz. Yes they are separate strings. And I what is "dict"? Sorry, I am still learning the code.

Comment: `dictionary` is an unordered collection that allows you store data as key/value pair. please check my answer.

Comment: I will do, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

instead of using string to store username and score, use `dict()` to store it as key/value pair,

First let's create a [dictionary](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_dictionaries.asp),

```
data = {"Ethan":15,
        "James":20,
        "Daniel":7}
```

Now use `sorted()` function to sort items of dictionary, you can get dictionary items using `dict.items()`. `dict.items()` gives you list of [tuple](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_tuples.htm) in this format, `[('Ethan', 15), ('James', 20)]`. This list of tuple has name on index 0, and score on index 1, hence we need to sort it on index `1`. You can use [lambda](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lambda.asp) for provide `key` you want to use for sorting.

Finally use `reverse = True` because default behavior of `sorted()` is to sort in ascending order,

```
data_sorted = sorted(data.items(), key= lambda x:x[1], reverse=True)
```

Now open a file and write to it.

```
with open("d:/scores.txt","a") as score_file:
  for k,v in data_sorted:
     score_file.write("{}, {}\n".format(k, v))
```

Quick summary of what is happening above.

- Create a dictionary to store your data.
- use `data.items()` to get data out of dictionary in form of list of tuple.
- use `sorted()` function to sort this list of tuple on index `1`.
- use `reverse = True` for descending order.
- use `with open` to open a file and write sorted data to it.

Complete code,

```
data = {"Ethan": 15,"James": 20}

data_sorted = sorted(data.items(), key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)

with open("d:/scores.txt", "a") as score_file:
    for k, v in data_sorted: 
       score_file.write("{}, {}\n".format(k, v))
```

It will write to a file `scores.txt` in `d:/` drive (windows).

Comment: Please would you be able to break this down a bit for me?

Comment: i am adding explanation @ThatDude

Comment: What does the x:x[1] do? When I put it comes up with invalid syntax and highlights the "x".

Comment: @ThatDude please read about `lambda` to understand what `x: x[1]` is doing. essentially `lambda` is an anonymous function. In our case it is defining a key for sorting.

Comment: Right, I will go do some research on it, I appreciate the help a lot, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you're storing people and their scores in a dictionary, you can create a list of tuples from the dictionary that is sorted.

```
import operator
people = {'Jamie': 20, 'Ethan': 15, 'Daniel': 7, 'Ronald': 25, 'Jeff': 0}
sortedPeople = sorted(people.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1))
```

If you want to then write to a file, you just need to loop through the sorted list and write each value in the list.

Here is an example of how to get a list of people containing their name and their score.

```
people = {}

with open('file.txt', 'r') as f:
  for line in f:
    splitLine = (line.replace(',','')).split()
    people[splitLine[0]] = splitLine[1]
```

Each splitLine is a list of size 2, the first element is the name, the second is the score. You can then add to your blank dictionary by stating that the first element (the name) is the value and the second element (the number) is the key.

Comment: Thank you, I will try this out.

Comment: So I get this code, thank you. But I have all the names and scores stored in an external file, so how would I sort them in the code?

Comment: @ThatDude I updated the code with a way to read each line and add it to a dictionary.

Comment: Thank you, I will check it out.

Comment: the question was initially about writing to file not reading from a file. Its not a good practice to change your question entirely after people have answered. @ThatDude

Comment: @SufiyanGhori My question was about putting the values in size order. I'm guessing from your answer that you do that while writing to the text file.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe consider to create a dictionary and then you can sort of 'sort' the dictionary.

Here is a link with an example:
[How to sort python dictionary by keys](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html)

Example code is:

```
keylist = mydict.keys()
keylist.sort()
for key in keylist:
print "%s: %s" % (key, mydict[key])
```

Otherwise, there is also the function 'sorted' which sorts however the key, so in your case the names.

Lastly, there is a good website from python.org:

[How To: sorting](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html)

Comment: Thanks, I will check out that link.